# Code based on the fact that sphenic number has exactly 8 divisors

Tags: c, algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

// Count the number of divisors of a number
int countDivisor(int n)
{
    int divisors = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            if (n / i == i) { // count one divisor for square number
                divisors++;
            } else { // count both divisors for non-square
                divisors += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return divisors;
}

// Check if number is sphenic
bool isSphenic(int n)
{
    if (n >= 30 && countDivisor(n) == 8) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() 
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    if (isSphenic(n) == true) {
        printf("Sphenic number!");
    } else {
        printf("Not a sphenic number!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This C code based on the fact that sphenic number has exactly 8 divisors. If I input `n = 56`, the output will be `Sphenic number`. I know it's wrong but I can't find my error.

Comment: But a Sphenic number has 8 divisors because it is divisble by 3 primes (7 perms) and by 1. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphenic_number) says: ***The converse does not hold**. For example, 24 is not a sphenic number, but it has exactly eight divisors.*

Comment: Ruby has a method that expresses numbers in terms of their prime divisors. For example, `Prime.prime_division(360) #=> [[2, 3], [3, 2], [5, 1]]`, meaning `360 = (2^3)*(3^2)*(5^1)`. I mention this only because I expect many other languages would have similar methods or functions, either built into the language or part of a library. A Sphenic number is defined as a positive integer that equals the product of three distinct primes; that is, it equals the product of three primes each raised to the power of one...

Comment: ...In Ruby suppose we had `Prime.prime_division(238) #=> [[2, 1], [7, 1], [17, 1]]`. As `238` is seen to equal the product of three primes, each to the power of one, we conclude that `238` is a spherical number. In other words, once we obtain the number's prime decomposition--in whatever language is being used--we conclude it is a spherical number if it equals the product of three primes, each to the power of one.

Comment: So look for the equivalent of what in Ruby would be `Prime.prime_decomposition(n).transpose.last == [1,1,1].

Comment: consider replacing `i <= sqrt(n)` with `i * i <= n`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sphenic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphenic_number) are defined as numbers that are the product of 3 distinct primes.  While sphenic numbers do have exactly 8 divisors, not all numbers with 8 divisors are sphenic numbers.

**56** is **2<sup>3</sup> * 7**, so it is not a sphenic number but it does have 8 divisors: **1**, **2**, **4**, **7**, **8**, **14**, **28** and **56**.

Numbers with exactly 8 divisors fall in 3 distinct categories:

- the product of 3 distinct primes (sphenic numbers): 30, 42, 66, 70...
- the product of a prime and the cube of another prime: 24, 40, 54, 56...
- the seventh power of a prime: 128, 2187, 78125...

Here is a modified version:

```
bool isSphenic(int n) {
    int factors = 1;
    if (n < 2 * 3 * 5)
        return false;
    for (int p = 2; p <= n / p; p++) {
        if (n % p == 0) {
            factors++;
            n /= p;
            if (n % p == 0)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return factors == 3;
}
```

As suggested by [*@Dave*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2041077/dave), this code can be improved in 2 ways:

- handling 2 separately and only testing odd numbers (**2x** faster)
- the smallest prime factor must be < n<sup>1/3</sup>, so the search should stop earlier for primes and 2 almost primes. (an extra **3x** faster).

Here is a faster version:

```
bool isSphenic(int n) {
    int factors = 1;

    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        ++factors;
        n /= 2;
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            return false;
        for (int p = 3; p <= n / p; p += 2) {
            if (n % p == 0) {
                if (++factors > 3)
                    return false;
                n /= p;
                if (n % p == 0)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return factors == 3;
    }
    for (int p = 3; p * p <= n / p; p += 2) {
        if (n % p == 0) {
            ++factors;
            n /= p;
            if (n % p == 0)
                return false;
            for (p += 2; p <= n / p; p += 2) {
                if (n % p == 0) {
                    if (++factors > 3)
                        return false;
                    n /= p;
                    if (n % p == 0)
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return factors == 3;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Couple thoughts. Handle 2 separately and only check odd factors after that. Also, the smallest prime factor of n if n is sphenic is < n^(1/3) so you can stop early.

Comment: @Dave: good points! answer amended along your suggestion with a faster version (**6x** faster to find sphenic numbers up to 10,000,000.)

Comment: More code, 6x faster, that probably going to mess with some people’s minds. ;)

Comment: consider recomputing all primes in range `2 ... INT_MAX^1/3`. It should be a few hundreds at most for a typical `int`. Precomputing modulo Z(2^32) reciprocal would let replace costly integer division with a cheap multiplication.